# YQL changing structure of JSON

Tags: json, yql

I had a very simple Open Data Table definition which simply fetches some JSON from a source and returns it. Issue is the below original json

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "items": [
    {
      "values": {
        "0": [
          {
            "key": "val"
          }
        ],
        "5": [
          {
            "key": "val"
          }
        ],
        "6": [
          {
            "key": "val"
          }
        ],
        "test": [
          {
            "key": "val"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

seems to change to

```
{
  "results": {
   "json": {
    "size": "0",
    "items": {
     "values": {
      "_": [
       {
        "key": "val"
       },
       {
        "key": "val"
       },
       {
        "key": "val"
       }
      ],
      "test": {
       "key": "val"
      }
     }
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

Any thoughts on why this might be happening?

EDIT

Just wanted to add the open data table definition:-

```
<table xmlns="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/schema/table.xsd">
  <meta>
    <author>MyName</author>
    <documentationURL>...</documentationURL>
    <description>...</description>  
    <sampleQuery>SELECT * FROM {table}</sampleQuery>
  </meta>
  <bindings>
    <select itemPath="" produces="JSON">
      <urls>
        <url>http://myurl.com/items.json</url>
      </urls>
    </select>
  </bindings>
</table>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you've done/used to cause the result to change.

Comment: added the open data table definition file (in case that helps)